# Is there a way to ignore an out parameter from a method call when it's not needed?

Tags: c#

Here is the code that I have:

```
    private int _utcNow;
    private string _yymmdd;

    public void AddScreenHistory(int Seconds)
    {
        Helper.GetDates(out _yymmdd, out _utcNow);
        
        // _yymmdd is used
        // _utcNow is not used
    }
```

I have declared _utcNow as a private to avoid a compiler error, but is there a way that I can avoid declaring it at all?

Comment: Why not just use a local variable instead of a field? And even then you can use a discard in newer versions of C#: `Helper.GetDates(out var yymmdd, out _)`. Also consider rewriting `GetDates` so it actually returns something (as a tuple): `(string yymmdd, int utcNow) GetDates()` (and then invoke as, for example, `(var yymmdd, _) = Helper.GetDates();`). This tends to be clearer than `out` parameters, especially if you have more than one.

Comment: If you're using the most recent version of C#, you can just use the discard and declare it inline: `Helper.GetDates(out var _yymmdd, out var _)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just do this:

```
Helper.GetDates(out _yymmdd, out _);
```

Comment: The other answer is better. Give him the gong.

Answer (score 2):

**Prior to C#7**, you would need a variable (likely local) to dump the result in:

```cs
int discard;
Helper.GetDates(out _yymmdd, out discard);
```

If you are **using C# 7.0** or newer you can make use of the ["Discards" feature.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards)

```cs
Helper.GetDates(out _yymmdd, out _);
```

You can even discard more than one parameter at a time:

```cs
Helper.GetDates(out _, out _); // valid!
```

Note the "unnamed" placeholder `_`. Trying to reference it is a compiler error:

```cs
Helper.GetDates(out _yymmdd, out _);
Console.WriteLine(_); // error! See below
```

This can also be used to indicate that you are purposely discarding the result of a method call:

```cs
_ = SomeMethodThatReturnsValue();
```

Be careful though, there is some trickery in these two forms if you combine with `var`:

```cs
// this is a discard
Helper.GetDates(out _yymmdd, out var _);
Console.WriteLine(_); // error!

// this is not
var _ = SomeMethodThatReturnsValue();
Console.WriteLine(_); // no error!
```

The first case results in an error due to the discard but the second case declares and assigns to a variable named `_`. Even more interesting is the following which combines both syntaxes but only declares one variable (the output is "True"):

```cs
var _ = int.TryParse("1",out var _);
Console.WriteLine(_);
```

If you already happened to have a variable named `_` *in scope* then the syntax no longer becomes a discard.

```cs
int _;
Helper.GetDates(out _yymmdd, out _); 
Console.WriteLine(_); // valid and will hold the out parameter's value
```

As mentioned in the comments, if you rewrote `GetDates` such that it returned a *tuple*, you could discard the portion you don't want:

```cs
public static (string, int) GetDates()
{
   return ("210408", 12345);
} 

// usage, tuple discard
(_yymmdd, _) = Helper.GetDates();
```

Comment: In the case of `Helper.GetDates(out _yymmdd, out var _)`, this will *not* declare a variable named `_`, it's still a discard. As older versions of C# did not allow `var` declarations in parameters, this does not break backwards compatibility, although it is a little inconsistent with `var _ = ...` (which is not a discard).

Comment: @JeroenMostert answer updated. It seems I should've read the link I provided! Lol. I just assumed discard always for that case. Interesting. Thanks!